# Karma - reinitialize browser for describe block

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm currently having the following problem:

In a karma unit test, I have two describe blocks. In both of them, I'm defining an element, compile it and add it to the body, just like the following:

```
element = angular.element('<div>some content</div>');

element = $compile(element)(scope);

angular.element("body").append(element);
```

The problem is, that the second describe block conflicts with the first one, because the browser window stays open all the time.

Concrete, in the second describe block, I'm checking for an HTML element toBeNull(), which should be null, but actually it is already defined from the first describe block (because it's the same brwoser instance).

So my question now is: Is there any way I can reopen or reinitialize the browser window for the second describe block, so I get a complete new document?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `describe` block so that at whatever the block sets up in the DOM is torn down at the end of the test. Runners that use `describe` blocks typically have an `after` or `afterAll` hook you can put in your block to perform the tear down after all the tests in the block have run.

Something like:

```
afterAll(function () {
  angular.element(element).remove();
});
```

Then the next block can start with a clean slate.

Comment: Can you be more precise how this works to completely clear the DOM then? How can I use afterAll to clear then?

Comment: I've added a code snippet. This ultimately uses jQuery's `remove()` method which ensures that the event listeners added with jQuery and all the `$.data` stuff is cleaned up at removal.

Comment: actually, this doesn't work... I have a guess why: With the line, only the element is removed, but it's still in the DOM, isn't it? (because I appended it to body beofre)..

Comment: When you use `angular.element`, the element passed is returned wrapped in `jQuery()`? Then you call [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) on it, which removes it from the DOM. Where it is in the DOM does not matter. It could be in `head`, in `body`, a child of anything else. It does not matter. It essentially does `if (element && element.parentNode) element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` (plus handler and `$.data` cleanup). It does not matter what `element` is a child of because it uses `element.parentNode`. Now, there may be *other things* in your code that are causing problems.

Comment: I just tried something: I put a console.log(element) before and after the line you provided, and both times I'm getting the same log. Is this normal? If yes, how could I check, that the line even did anything?

Comment: `console.log(element)` by itself won't tell you anything about whether the element is in the DOM. The element still exists after removal, even if it is not in the DOM. What you could do is `console.log(element.parentNode)`. Should be `null` after removal.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` as result, but actually I'm even getting `undefined` when I put the console.log before the removal (so it's not even executing the line, because it doesn't pass the `if` condition **Edit**: I actually mistakenly included the tag `karma-runner` instead of `karma-jasmine`, acutally I'm not using runners, but the function afterAll() itself seems to be executed (otherwise I wouldn't get any log result at all